# How to manage unicity in my buisness logic layer?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-core, architecture, ef-core-2.2

In a aspnetcore mvc executing context .

I have this simple entity.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name{ get; private set; }
    public string Code { get; private set; }

    private Foo() { }

    public Foo(string Name, string Code)
    {
        GuardClauses.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name,nameof(Name), "cannot be null or empty");
        GuardClauses.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Code, nameof(Code), "cannot be null or empty");  
        this.Nom = Nom;
        this.Code = Code;
    } 
}
```

In my DbContext I have this code field/constraint that ensures the Code is unique from a persistence point of view.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Foo>()
        .HasIndex(u => u.Code)
        .IsUnique();
}
```

I want the addNewFoo method in my service class to ensure that for all Foos in my Application the property code is unique, before adding it.

I try as much as I can to respect persistence ignorance principle, but I'm not as skilled as I wish to do that.

For starters, is it the role of a Builder to determine if the Code field is Unique?

Secondly I know that in my validation layer I can determine if there is an existing foo already with the same Code that the actual foo I'm currently trying to add. But this approchah isn't thread safe or transactional.

The fact is I don't want to wait the moment I add my foo too have a SqlException, just to know it cannot be done.

What is the best approach to ensure unicity in my application with the 
Fail Fast principle in mind.

Comment: Unless you're building a single user system, **no** amount of prechecking can help because someone else might be *about* to insert the duplicate item and succeed between the point at which you've completed your prechecks and the point at which you perform your *actual* insert. You have to handle this exception *anyway*. Why add more code/layers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I am aware of what you say, I was just hopping there was another approach to deal with that. And SqlException is not very friendly about the reason why. (have to read sql result code... kind of magic number...).

Comment: https://github.com/ardalis/DDD-NoDuplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is't a concrete example or description of a system I will generalize a bit. If you provide a concrete example I can add additional info. Every solution has a **Context** to which it applies to best and of course there is always a trade-off

Let's ask couple of querstions regarding the nature of this **Code** and what it represents

1. Who is responcible for the **Code** generation: the **User** of the system or the **System** itself?
2. Can the **Code** be completely random (UUID for example)?
3. Is the code generated by some special algorithm ([SSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number) or maybe a [CarPartNumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_number) that is composed of different parts with a special meaning)

*And one more very important question:*

4. *How frequently do we expect these unique violations to occur?*

If the answer to question **2** is Yes, then you don't have a problem. You can have a duplicate UUID's, but the chances are very low. You can add a **Unique Constrant** to you DB just in case and treat this violation as a normal error that you don't care about since it's gonna happen every once in a million years.

If the answer to question **3** is Yes, then we have a different sittuation. In a multi-user system you cannot avoid concurrency. There are couple of way to deal with the sittuation:

- Option 1: [Optimistic Offline Lock](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html)
- Option 2: [Pessimistic Offline Lock](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html)
- Option 3: If **System** is generating codes, have a special service and queue code generation requests.

If you choose to use a lock, you can either lock the whole resource **Foo** or only lock the **Code** generation.

**Option 1**:

You will have to handle the SQLException. This one is used in most applications today because it ensures smooth **User Experience** by not causing the application to stall for large amounts of time because someone has locked a resource.

You can use an abstraction for example a Repository. Define your own application level exception UniqueCodeViolationException that will be thrown by the Repository. The repository will try{}catch{} the SQLException, process it and wrap it in UniqueCodeViolationException when is compares the error codes. This won't save you the check but at least if will hide the concrete errors and you will have the processing in only one place.

**Option2**:

Sometimes you realy need to ensure that there is no concurrency, so you use this option. In this case you will have to lock the process of creation of **Foo** for only one user and don't allow other to be able to even be able to open the dialog/form/page for creating **Foo** if there is a lock.

This ensures consistency and avoids the problem by creating a system that is basically unusable for multiple users that target the same **Foo**. It's quite possible that the application you are building will have only one person responsible for **Foo** creation or it may that concurrency is very low, so this may be a good solution.

I have friends who use this lock in an application for *Insurances*. Usually in their application one person is going to one office to make an *Insurance*. so the possibility of concurrency in the creation of an insurance for the same person is very low, but the cost of having multiple Insurances to the same person is very hight.

**Option 3:**

On the other hand If your Code is generated by the **System**, you can have a **CodeGenerationService** that deals with code generations and ensures that unique codes are generated. You can have a queue with these requests. In each generation operation in the Service you can check if this code exists and return an Error (or throw exception).

Now to question **4**. If you don't expect to have collisions often, just add a **Unique Constraint** in your DB and treat it as a general unexpected error. Add the check if the **Code** already exists and show an error if it does.

You still can have a concurrency here so there will be a slim change that one user will add a **Foo** and another will get an error "Oooops... something whent wrong.. please try again". Since this will happen once in a 100 years it's ok.

The last solution will make your system a lot simpler by ignoring special situations that can occur in rare situations.